# Python convert list into nested list based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 7, 0]
```

expected output

```
result = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [4,6,7]]
```

Split the list when a zero occur; add all the non-zero numbers to a new list till the next zero

This is what I have tried:

```
res = []
tmp = []
for i in data:
  if i == 0 and len(tmp) > 0:
    res.append(tmp)
    tmp = []
  elif i != 0:
    tmp.append(i)
```

I am wondering is there a pythonic way of doing the same...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 7, 0]

result = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(data, key=bool) if k]
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [4, 6, 7]]
```

The grouping key function uses the fact that `bool` maps `0` to False and all other `ints` to `True`. You could be more explicit and use

`key=lambda n: n != 0`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [more_itertools.split_at](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_at):

```
from more_itertools import split_at

data = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 7, 0]

list(filter(None, split_at(data, lambda x: x==0 )))
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [4, 6, 7]]
```